# How do I generate a tournament schedule in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I have been searching everywhere, including the Stack Overflow archives, for an answer of how to do this, I tried rolling my own, but have come up short, so I decided I would post my request here.

I need to take an arbitrary (even) number of items in an array and return with item paired with another item in the array. I need the output of the code to be the same as the output example I have included below.

Input:

```
('A'..'H').to_a
```

Output:

```
[[['A','H'], ['B','G'], ['C','F'], ['D','E']],
 [['A','G'], ['B','F'], ['C','E'], ['D','H']],
 [['A','F'], ['B','E'], ['C','D'], ['G','H']],
 [['A','E'], ['B','D'], ['C','H'], ['F','G']],
 [['A','D'], ['B','C'], ['E','G'], ['F','H']],
 [['A','C'], ['B','H'], ['D','G'], ['E','F']],
 [['A','B'], ['C','G'], ['D','F'], ['E','H']]]
```

Any ideas?

Here's what I have done so far. It's a bit dirty, and it's not returning in the order I need.

```
items = ('A'..'H').to_a
combinations = []

1.upto(7) do |index|
  curitems = items.dup
  combination = []
  1.upto(items.size / 2) do |i|
    team1 = curitems.delete_at(0)
    team2 = curitems.delete_at(curitems.size - index) || curitems.delete_at(curitems.size - 1)
    combination << [team1, team2]
  end
  combinations << combination
end

pp combinations
```

The output is close, but not in the right order:

```
[[["A", "H"], ["B", "G"], ["C", "F"], ["D", "E"]],
 [["A", "G"], ["B", "F"], ["C", "E"], ["D", "H"]],
 [["A", "F"], ["B", "E"], ["C", "D"], ["G", "H"]],
 [["A", "E"], ["B", "D"], ["C", "H"], ["F", "G"]],
 [["A", "D"], ["B", "C"], ["E", "G"], ["F", "H"]],
 [["A", "C"], ["B", "H"], ["D", "E"], ["F", "G"]],
 [["A", "B"], ["C", "G"], ["D", "H"], ["E", "F"]]]
```

You'll notice that my code gets me two D<->H combinations (last line and second line) and that won't work.

**My understanding of the OP's requirements [FM]:**

- Given `N` teams (for example, 8
  teams: `A..H`).
- Create a tournament schedule,
  consisting of `R` rounds of play (7
  in our example) and `G` games (28 in
  our example).
- Where every team plays every other team exactly once.
- Where every team plays once in each round.
- And (the hard part) where the
  ordering of games within a round
  works like this:
- The top-ranked team (A) plays the
  low-ranked team (H) first.
- If a candidate matchup is rejected
  for violating the no-repeat rule, put
  the low-ranked team on the
  "back-burner" and form the other
  matchups first. Then matchup the
  back-burner teams using the same
  rules. (For example: in Round 2, the
  first candidate matchup, `A-H`, is
  rejected as a repeat, so Game 1 will
  be `A-G`, and `H` will sit on the back
  burner, to be paired with `D` as the
  last game in the round).
- When adding teams to the back-burner,
  add them to the front of that list
  (i.e., preserve rank ordering on the
  back-burner as well).
- **Note**: Round 5 is the tricky one. The
  first 2 games are straightforward.
  The 3rd game would then be `E-H`;
  however, that creates a scenario
  where the 4th game would be a repeat
  (`F-G`). So the algorithm needs to
  backtrack, reject the `E-H` pairing
  and instead go for `E-G` in the 3rd
  game.

Comment: Are there any performance constraints? What size arrays? When you say it needs to be the same, does this include the order?

Comment: Yes, it needs to be in that order. (It needs to replace an existing process that is currently manually done and the customer is set in their ways.)

Comment: Could you explain what the order is? I'm not sure I can guess the pattern.

Comment: I apologize, I realized I missed a dimension. I constructed that array by hand from a sheet and didn't notice that I missed that. Take another look and it shoud be more clear. Thanks!!!

Comment: I have updated the posting with some code I wrote that gets me 90% there, but still fails to get the right order.

Comment: Dumb question I'm sure, but can you just hard-code it? Your code is already longer than the array.

Comment: I would definitely prefer that, but the problem is that #1 the letters are for prototyping sake and in the end refer to objects, and #2 the number of items in the initial list will vary. This is for a team matching system for a sporting event.

Comment: can you describe the ordering?  it makes no sense - why is [E,G] separated from [E,F] (and preceding the [D.?] entries??

Comment: I think it's going to have to e dirty because your ordering doesn't resemble any natural ordering that I know of

Comment: @rwl4 Could you explain how it is done manually? There must be a way to capture the manual logic in code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I can get your 8-team example right, but I don't know how to generalize the tweak. But maybe this'll get you thinking...

```
games = (1...teams.size).map do |r|
  t = teams.dup
  (0...(teams.size/2)).map do |_|
    [t.shift,t.delete_at(-(r % t.size + (r >= t.size * 2 ? 1 : 0)))]
  end
end
```

Comment: Was anyone able to make this snippet work for any quantity of teams?

Comment: See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/26323225/197944 for a gem working on odd and even number of teams.

Answer (score 5):

You seem want a round-robin schedule.  The principle is easy:

If you start with this setup (teams in the upper row playing against the corresponding lower team):

```
A B C D
H G F E
```

you set one team as fixed (e.g., A) and rotate the rest (e.g., clockwise):

```
A H B C     A G H B     A F G H     A E F G    A D E F    A C D E  
G F E D     F E D C     E D C B     D C B H    C B H G    B H G F
```

Voilà, 7 rounds, and every team plays each other team.

Edit:  I changed the enumeration order in this example to reflect your example output, but this only gets the opponents of `A` right.

Answer (score 4):

I apologize for the Python-ness of this code. With any luck, someone will translate.

```
def tourney(teams):
    N = len(teams)
    R = N-1 # rounds
    M = N/2 # matches per round
    sched = [[None] * M for i in range(R)]
    played = set()

    def fill(i, t):
        # Replenish t at the start of each round.
        if i % M == 0:
            t = teams[:]

        # Pick out the highest-seeded team left in t.
        topseed = t.pop(min(range(len(t)), key=lambda i: teams.index(t[i])))

        # Try opponents in reverse order until we find a schedule that works.
        for j, opp in reversed(list(enumerate(t))):
            match = topseed, opp
            if match not in played:
                # OK, this is match we haven't played yet. Schedule it.
                sched[i // M][i % M] = match
                played.add(match)

                # Recurse, if there are any more matches to schedule.
                if i + 1 == R * M or fill(i + 1, t[j+1:]+t[:j]):
                    return True  # Success!

                # If we get here, we're backtracking. Unschedule this match.
                played.remove(match)
        return False

    if not fill(0, []):
        raise ValueError("no schedule exists")
    return sched
```

Comment: Nice job. The funky ordering (assuming that I described it correctly) made this a tough one.

Comment: FM: You did an amazing job reverse-engineering that, and I wouldn't have bothered with this without your explanation.

Comment: Apparently it works up to 4 teams (or maybe for even numbers only), then at least one team does not get all matchups properly scheduled.

Comment: In my defense, the question does say "arbitrary (even) number".

Comment: If you have an odd number of teams then you can adjust this so in the first round only there is an extra team named "BYE" that is the lowest seeded team.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
[*'A'..'H'].permutation(2).to_a
 => [["A", "B"], ["A", "C"], ["A", "D"], ["A", "E"], ["A", "F"], ["A", "G"], ["A", "H"], ["B", "A"], ["B", "C"], ["B", "D"], ["B", "E"], ["B", "F"], ["B", "G"],....
```

Edit: Just noticed the output is not in your desired format, but maybe it's still useful for somebody else.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an implementation in ruby 1.8.6 according to FM's specification giving the correct output for 8 teams (Many thanks to FM for the great work!):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'pp'
require 'enumerator'

class Array
  # special round robin scheduling
  def schedule
    res, scheduled = [], []
    (length-1).times { dup.distribute(scheduled, []) }
    # convert list of games to list of rounds
    scheduled.each_slice(length/2) {|x| res.push x}
    aux = res.inject {|a, b| a+b}
    raise if aux.uniq.length != aux.length
    res
  end
  # pair the teams in self and backburner and add games to scheduled
  def distribute(scheduled, backburner)
    # we are done if list is empty and back burners can be scheduled
    return true if empty? && backburner.empty?
    return backburner.distribute(scheduled, []) if empty?
    # take best team and remember if back burner list offered alternatives
    best, alternatives = shift, !backburner.empty?
    # try each team starting from the last
    while other = pop do
      # add team to the back burner list if best played it already
      if scheduled.include? [best, other]
        backburner.unshift(other)
        next
      end
      # schedule the game
      scheduled.push [best, other]
      # try if rest can be scheduled
      return true if dup.distribute(scheduled, backburner.dup)
      # if not unschedule game and add other to back burner list
      scheduled.pop
      backburner.unshift(other)
    end
    # no possible opponent was found, so try alternatives from back burners list
    return alternatives && backburner.unshift(best).distribute(scheduled, [])
  end
end

pp %w{ A B C D E F G H }.schedule

__END__

Output:
[[["A", "H"], ["B", "G"], ["C", "F"], ["D", "E"]],
 [["A", "G"], ["B", "F"], ["C", "E"], ["D", "H"]],
 [["A", "F"], ["B", "E"], ["C", "D"], ["G", "H"]],
 [["A", "E"], ["B", "D"], ["C", "H"], ["F", "G"]],
 [["A", "D"], ["B", "C"], ["E", "G"], ["F", "H"]],
 [["A", "C"], ["B", "H"], ["D", "G"], ["E", "F"]],
 [["A", "B"], ["C", "G"], ["D", "F"], ["E", "H"]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

I created a gem, [round_robin_tournament](https://github.com/ssaunier/round_robin_tournament) which you might find useful.

Just run

```
students = %w(John Paul Ringo George)
teams = RoundRobinTournament.schedule(students)
```

And `teams` will be an array of each day, each day being an array of couples.

Answer (score 1):

I finally had time to look at this again. This is a Ruby version of Jason's answer, with a few simplifications and a couple of good ideas from jug's answer.

```
require 'pp'

def tournament (teams)
    teams.reverse!

    # Hash of hashes to keep track of matchups already used.
    played = Hash[ * teams.map { |t| [t, {}] }.flatten ]

    # Initially generate the tournament as a list of games.
    games = []
    return [] unless set_game(0, games, played, teams, nil)

    # Convert the list into tournament rounds.
    rounds = []
    rounds.push games.slice!(0, teams.size / 2) while games.size > 0
    rounds
end

def set_game (i, games, played, teams, rem)
    # Convenience vars: N of teams and total N of games.
    nt  = teams.size
    ng  = (nt - 1) * nt / 2

    # If we are working on the first game of a round,
    # reset rem (the teams remaining to be scheduled in
    # the round) to the full list of teams.
    rem = Array.new(teams) if i % (nt / 2) == 0

    # Remove the top-seeded team from rem.
    top = rem.sort_by { |tt| teams.index(tt) }.pop
    rem.delete(top)

    # Find the opponent for the top-seeded team.
    rem.each_with_index do |opp, j|
        # If top and opp haven't already been paired, schedule the matchup.
        next if played[top][opp]
        games[i] = [ top, opp ]
        played[top][opp] = true

        # Create a new list of remaining teams, removing opp
        # and putting rejected opponents at the end of the list.
        rem_new = [ rem[j + 1 .. rem.size - 1], rem[0, j] ].compact.flatten

        # Method has succeeded if we have scheduled the last game
        # or if all subsequent calls succeed.
        return true if i + 1 == ng
        return true if set_game(i + 1, games, played, teams, rem_new)

        # The matchup leads down a bad path. Unschedule the game
        # and proceed to the next opponent.
        played[top][opp] = false
    end

    return false
end

pp tournament(ARGV)
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a gem recently that help in the process of generating round-robin schedules. You might  [give it a try](http://flamontagne.github.com/rrschedule/).

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer here gave me trouble.  Seems related to the delete_at approach where you are moving backwards on the array of teams.  Inevitbaly two teams play each other more than once before they should.  I only noticed it when I went to 16 teams, but I think it happens at 8 teams as well...

so I coded Svante's algo which is clever and works with any number of teams.  Also I'm rotating counter-clockwise, *not* clockwise

assuming teams is a model object here, and num_teams is the number of teams

```
  @tms = teams.all    
  matchups_play_each_team_once = (0...num_teams-1).map do |r|
    t = @tms.dup
    first_team = t.shift
    r.times do |i|
      t << t.shift
    end
    t = t.unshift(first_team)  
    tms_away = t[0...num_teams/2]
    tms_home = t[num_teams/2...num_teams].reverse
    (0...(num_teams/2)).map do |i|
      [tms_away[i],tms_home[i]]
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on this information in [this link](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/54715.html) the following Ruby code is what I use to generate round-robin scheduling:

```
def round_robin(teams)
  raise "Only works for even number of teams" unless teams.length.even?
  first = teams.shift                               # Put one team in the middle, not part of the n-gon
  size  = teams.length                              # The size of the n-gon without one team
  pairs = (1..(size/2)).map{ |i| [i,size-i].sort }  # The 'lines' that connect vertices in the n-gon
  (0...size).map{                                   
    teams.unshift( teams.pop )                      # Rotate the n-gon
    # Combine the special case with the vertices joined by the lines
    [ [ first, teams[0] ], *pairs.map{ |a,b| [ teams[a], teams[b] ] } ]
  }
end

teams    = ('A'..'H').to_a
schedule = round_robin(teams)
puts schedule.map{ |round| round.map{ |teams| teams.join }.join(' ') }
#=> AH BG CF DE
#=> AG HF BE CD
#=> AF GE HD BC
#=> AE FD GC HB
#=> AD EC FB GH
#=> AC DB EH FG
#=> AB CH DG EF
```